# How do I find a partial string in a Mongo database using a superset string?

Tags: mongodb

If my database contains entries with the following string values for the "key" field:

```
"a,b,c"
"a,b,z"
"a,b,c,d,e,f,z"
"d,e,f,g"
"d,e,f,g,z"
"h,i"
```

And I have a string like this:

```
"a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h"
```

How do I find the entries where the value of the key field matches the start of my string? E.g. I want to find the entry where the value of the key field is "a,b,c".

How do I find the entries where the value of the key field matches any part of my string? E.g. I want to find the entries where the value of the key field is "a,b,c" and "d,e,f,g".

To give some context in case anyone thinks this is a pointless task, I want to do stack matching. I will have entries in a database that identify bugs by the first N frames of the stack and then I want to identify bug(s) by the stack obtained from a core dump.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your data structure, can you post a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: Agree with @felix - it's not clear what kind of data you have. You are talking about strings, but samples look more like arrays

Comment: They are strings. A sample document might look like: {_id: id, issue_id: 12345, description: "Core dump in malloc()", stack: '_int_malloc,calloc,MyAllocFunc"}

Comment: Clarified that everything is strings by adding quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the $where operator. An example in Python, where `search_string` is the string we want to find matches with, is:

```
search_string = 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h'
js_check = 'function () { var search_string=\'' + search_string + '\'; return search_string.indexOf(this.key) >= 0; }'
matches = my_collection.find({'$where': js_check})
```